# Is the past simple correct in this construction?

Tags: usage, sequence-of-tenses

As far as l know using the present perfect in the following  construction is very common. But sometimes l hear some speakers use the past simple in the main clause.

I spent $ 2000 since l came home.

My question is: is it OK to use this construction?

Comment: Why not? The example you gave does not give enough context to justify using a perfect tense. As long as the spending has already ended, simple past should be OK.

Comment: That means it' OK to use it informally

Comment: Informal speech can be whatever the speaker is used to hearing or speaking. But as I mentioned about context, the broader conversation using your phrase may influence the grammar used.